# How to use backbone collections to filter models

Tags: d3.js, backbone.js

I have implemented an app with multiple models and views but collections are a bit troublesome to understand. So far I have achieved my goals without the use of collections and now I am required to manipulate a set of models based on the attributes. And I'm pretty sure I need collections now.

I have the following structure(which is way simpler than the actual implementation):

```
app.Connector=Backbone.Model.extend({
    line: //a d3 line object
    source: //a d3 group
    target: //a d3 group  
    // and some functions
});

app.Set=Backbone.Collections.extend({
    model:app.Connector;
    url:"/set"  //what is the purpose of url?
});

var set=new app.Set();
//multiple connectors are initialized
```

Say I have a d3 object `obj`. How can I get a list/array of the Connectors that have `obj` as the `target`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var filtered = set.filter(d=>d.get('target') == obj)
```

I find the Backbone `get` functions to be too verbose, so i like to transform the collection into json before filtering.

```
var filtered = _.filter(set.toJSON(),d=>d.target == obj)
```

Comment: I tried it but the returned array is empty. Check the JSfiddle on https://jsfiddle.net/sachid/qko7vnxv/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qko7vnxv/2/ You created a model, then you created a collection. You never put the model in the collection!

Comment: Thanks. One last question. If I want to add all `Connector` s to a pre-initiated `Set`, is there anything wrong with saying `set.add(this)` in the model's initiate?

Comment: And a side-issue, when I format the code in the IDE(netbeans) the `d=>d` is separated by spaces, resulting a syntax error. Is it a problem with the IDE or something else? What does `=>` actually stand for?

Comment: That doesn't seem like the proper way to do it. The model shouldn't have any knowledge of the collection. You should add all models to the `Set`'s constructor.

Comment: `d=>d` is EMCA 6 syntax, your IDE may not recognize it. Spaces don't matter,